# Creating a deb file with dpkg-deb does not add file in /etc/ to conffiles

Tags: linux, debian, configuration-files, dpkg

I'm trying to get files in /etc to behave like supposedly conffiles are meant to behave by default.

Docs indicate I don't have to do anything to mark files in /etc as conffiles.

But I'm creating a deb with dpgk-deb and when I install it with dpkg -i  it always overwrites the users changes to file in /etc/ with new version from the package. It never asks the quesstion about which to use.

I have tried manually adding all  files in /etc to a DEBIAN/conffiles files.

```
dpkg --status
```

Does not show a conffiles: section at all for my package.

Answer (score 0):

the ordinary Debian workflow is to add any config-files to `debian/conffiles` (resp. `debian/<pkgname>.conffiles` if you are building multiple binary packages from a single source package).

note that `debian/` directory is all lowercase and sits in the root of the packaging dir. you really should read a [packaging introduction](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian) and start with a `debian/` skeleton created by something like `dh_make`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not increment the Version: in the control file the
conffiles feature does not work.

Incrementing the Version: prevented the problem from happening again.  There is no need to create a conffiles if you put configuration files in /etc

Comment: Actually no, when not using `debhelper`, simply putting the files under /etc will not suffice, as  `dpkg-deb` does not have any filesystem policy and will not consider those as *conffiles*. This is usually done transparently by things such as `debhelper`, and that's why it might seem like  `dpkg-deb` is doing it for you, but that's not the case.